# Configuration data for the SDK Library

Tags: node.js, configuration, architecture, sdk

I'm programming two pieces of a software.

1. SDK (that will live under node_modules)
2. Application that uses SDK

I want the SDK to be generic and able to work on some configuration data passed by the application.

Question is, there are several actors (.js modules) within the SDK, how the rest of the actors (.js modules) can access the configuration data that I've passed to the main SDK module (lib/index.js), or how that works in nodejs SDK world when it comes to configuration data.

The configuration data is highly reusable and every actor in my SDK library would need this configuration data, my objective is to pass it once to the main JS module (index.js) and then rest of the modules reach out to this for their operations.

I hope it's clear and I can further refine my question, please comment.

**Edit.**

Let's say I've app.js

```
var SDK = require("./sdk");
SDK("key", "secret");

var M1 = require("./sdk/m1");
var m1 = new M1();
m1.doSomething();

var M2 = require("./sdk/m2");
var m2 = new M2();
m2.doSomethikng()
```

**SDK.js**

```
var SDK = function(key, secret) {
    this.key = key;
    this.secret = secret;
}

module.exports = SDK;
```

**sdk/M1.js**

```
var M1 = function() {}
M1.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    //uses key and secret
}
module.exports = M1;
```

**sdk/M2.js**

```
var M2 = function() {}
M2.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    //uses key and secret
}
module.exports = M2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pattern that I've discovered without Factory methods on the main module (can't have factory method for each of my several modules) while the other actors still have access to config data which is held by main module only.

**app.js**

```
var SDK = require("./sdk");

SDK.config = {key: "key", secret: "secret"};

var m1 = new SDK.M1();
m1.doSomething();
```

**sdk.js**

```
var SDK = function(){};

SDK.config = {key: null, secret: null};

module.exports = SDK;

require("./m1"); //executing other modules to make it work
```

**m1.js**

```
var SDK = require("./sdk");

var M1 = function(){};

M1.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    var config = SDK.config //getting access to main module's config data
};

SDK.M1 = M1;
```

And same with the other actors of the system, there's no passing of config parameters around and forcing each actor to have a similar constructor.

Comment: I see, you are sharing a module cached field (public static in Object Oriented terms). This would work. Just beware of the cyclic dependency SDK <--> M1.

Comment: It's one way, In sdk.js I'm not assigning any property of `SDK` to `M1`, I'm only requiring it to execute `require("./m1")`, it's the M1 who's setting itself to a property of SDK, so I'm not sure where is the cyclic dependency?

Comment: `m1.js` contains `require("./sdk")` and `sdk.js` contains `require("./m1")`. That makes a cyclic `require()` loop.

Comment: true, I've tried to be careful, putting requires at the end when I'm really done with exporting the parent module, https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: @S.D. can you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111923/multitenant-configuration-data-for-the-sdk-library

Answer (score 0):

There are many architectural ways to do it, difficult to say which one is the best without knowing your use case and what creational pattern you use.

A simple example could be, using factories which pass the configuration (or a copy) to each other: basically you let your sdk create its dependencies

```
// mysdk/index.js
const myLib = require('./lib/myLib');
module.exports = function sdkFactory(options){
  const {configuration} = options;
  const libInstance = myLib(configuration);
 //your sdk api
  return {
    method1:function(){
      //whatever using the libInstance
      return libInstance.foo();
    }, 
   //etc
  }
}
```

So your client code can use it

```
const sdkFactory = require('sdk');
const sdk = sdkFactory({configuration:{prp:'val'}});
sdk.method1();
//etc
```

You can use [dependency injection pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and many others.

I suggest you to get a look at the source code of popular libraries you use everyday so you can have an idea of good/bad practices

Comment: Laurent, thanks for your attempt, please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

In simplest form: just require everything external in constructor.

*Actor.js*

```
function Actor(sdkConfig,config){
   this.sdkConfig = sdkconfig;
   this.config = config;
}

Actor.prototype.doSomething = function(){};

.....

Actor.prototype.doSomethingElse = function(){};

module.exports = Actor;
```

Then, grant access to new instances of Actors, via the Sdk instance:

*Sdk.js*

```
function Sdk(config){
  this.config = config;
}

Sdk.prototype.createActor = function(actorConfig){
   return new Actor(this.config,actorConfig);
}

module.exports = Sdk;
```

*Usage*

```
var Sdk = require("Sdk");

var sdk = new Sdk({"sdkSetting":true});

var actor = sdk.createActor({"actorSetting":false});
```

Comment: I've edited my code a bit, is there a way to do it without factories, and not asking everytime sdk to create modules, it has to do something with module caching with node.js

Comment: @user2727195 In truly decoupled code, all external dependencies should be provided at construction, as is in examples above. However you can also refactor to pass the SDK instance to Actor constructor: `new Actor(sdk, actorConfig)`.

Comment: please have a look at my answer, thanks for your approach as well