# Multitenant configuration data for the SDK Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, sdk, multi-tenant

This question builds on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38047456/2727195) to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888699/configuration-data-for-the-sdk-library), where I was looking for a solution to share configuration data between actors (nodejs modules) of a system (SDK) without using Factory pattern.

This time I need to make the SDK multi-tenant by providing different configuration data for distinct SDK instances.

**app.js**

```
var SDKAcctA = require("./sdk");
SDKAcctA.config = {key: "key", secret: "secret"};

var SDKAcctB = require("./sdk");
SDKAcctB.config = {key: "key2", secret: "secret2"};

// use both of them concurrently without each one overriding the config data of the other

var mA = new SDKAcctA.M1();
mA.doSomething();

var mB = new SDKAcctB.M1();
mB.doSomething();
```

**sdk.js**

```
var SDK = function(){};

SDK.config = {key: null, secret: null};

module.exports = SDK;

require("./m1"); //executing other modules to make it work
```

**m1.js**

```
var SDK = require("./sdk");

var M1 = function(){};

M1.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    var config = SDK.config //getting access to main module's config data
};

SDK.M1 = M1;
```

**Question:**

Right now the configuration data is getting overriden by the other instance and that's what the issue is. Please advise.

Comment: `require("./sdk")` alone cannot return a new instance, it even caches the required module. Better export a function `sdklib = require('sdklib');  var sdk1 = sdklib(config1)`. `Expressjs` follows this pattern.

Comment: @S.D. if you notice the m1 is a static property on SDK, meaning a `require('./sdk') in m1.js will lead to a new object if I export a function and I'd not be able to access all static properites. The conflict is because of static properties vs. different configuration data